# How can I use Vi on Windows?

Tags: windows, vim, vi

Other people who have asked this question had answers about downloading Vim from Vim.org, but that website doesn't respond.

Are there other ways to use Vi on Windows?

Comment: There isn't an obvious way to get the installer aside from downloading it from vim.org, and just now I see that the website seems to be working fine for me. It does take longer than I expected to start the download after I clicked to download the installer (~30 seconds), so maybe give it some extra time or try downloading it at a low-traffic time?

Answer (score 0):

You can download from [here](https://www.vim.org/download.php#pc), it's working

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple to set up vim on windows, although I just tested and the download seems to be surprisingly slow, as if vim.org is experiencing a lot of traffic right now.

If you are having trouble getting the download from https://www.vim.org/download.php to work, there is [a list of mirrors](https://www.vim.org/mirrors.php) that you can try.

Once you get the windows installer, use the 'full' installation type option for best results.